# MySQL login-path issues with clustercheck script used in xinetd

Tags: mysql, haproxy, xinetd

## default: on

```
# description: mysqlchk 
service mysqlchk 
{ 
# this is a config for xinetd, place it in /etc/xinetd.d/
        disable = no 
        flags           = REUSE 
        socket_type     = stream 
        type            = UNLISTED
        port            = 9200 
        wait            = no 
        user            = root
        server          = /usr/bin/mysqlclustercheck
        log_on_failure  += USERID 
        only_from       = 0.0.0.0/0
        #
        # Passing arguments to clustercheck
        # <user> <pass> <available_when_donor=0|1> <log_file> <available_when_readonly=0|1> <defaults_extra_file>"
        # Recommended: server_args   = user pass 1 /var/log/log-file 0 /etc/my.cnf.local"
        # Compatibility: server_args = user pass 1 /var/log/log-file 1 /etc/my.cnf.local"
        # 55-to-56 upgrade: server_args = user pass 1 /var/log/log-file 0 /etc/my.cnf.extra"
        #
        # recommended to put the IPs that need 
        # to connect exclusively (security purposes) 
        per_source      = UNLIMITED 
} 
 /etc/xinetd.d #
```

It is kind of strange that script works fine when run manually when it runs using /etc/xinetd.d/ , it is not working as expected.

```
In mysqlclustercheck script, instead of using --user= and passord= syntax, I am using --login-path= syntax
script runs fine when I run using command line but status for xinetd was showing signal 13. After debugging, I have found that even simple command like this is not working
mysql_config_editor print --all >>/tmp/test.txt

We don't see any output generated when it is run using xinetd ( mysqlclustercheck)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following instead of `/usr/bin/mysqlclustercheck`?

`server = /usr/bin/clustercheck`

I am wondering if you could test your binary location with the linux which command.

Answer (score 0):

A long time ago since this question was asked, but it just came to my attention.

First of all as mentioned, Percona Cluster Control script is called `clustercheck`, so make sure you are using the correct name and correct path.

Secondly, since the server script runs fine from command line, it seems to me that the path of `mysql` client command is not known by the `xinetd` when it runs the  Cluster Control script.

Since the `mysqlclustercheck` script as it is offered from Percona, it uses only the binary name `mysql` without specifying the absolute path I suggest you do the following:

Find where mysql client command is located on your system:

```
ccloud@gal1:~> sudo -i
gal1:~ # which mysql
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql
gal1:~ #
```

then edit script `/usr/bin/mysqlclustercheck` and in the following line:
`MYSQL_CMDLINE="mysql --defaults-extra-file=$DEFAULTS_EXTRA_FILE -nNE --connect-timeout=$TIMEOUT \`
place the exact path of mysql client command you found in the previous step.

I also see that you are *not* using MySQL connection credentials for connecting to MySQL server. `mysqlclustercheck` script as it is offered from Percona, it uses User/Password in order to connect to MySQL server.

So normally, you should execute the script in the command line like:

```
gal1:~ # /usr/sbin/clustercheck haproxy haproxyMySQLpass
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain
```

Where haproxy/haproxyMySQLpass is the MySQL connection user/pass for HAProxy monitoring user.

Additionally, you should specify them to your script's  `xinetd` settings like:

```
 server          = /usr/bin/mysqlclustercheck
 server_args     =  haproxy haproxyMySQLpass
```

Last but not least, the signal 13 you are getting is because you try to write something in a script run by `xinetd`. If for example in your `mysqlclustercheck`  you try to add a statement like

```
echo "debug message"
```

you probably going to see the broken pipe signal (13 in POSIX).

Finally, I had issues with this script using SLES 12.3 and I finally manage to run it not as 'nobody' but as 'root'.

Hope it helps